# converges uniformly to a limit

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove that the following sequence of functions,

$$f_n(x) = \sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}$$

converges uniformly to its limit.

So the first part I clearly needed to calculate the limit of this function, so I went ahead and did the following,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$$

But now how do I show that $f_n$ converges uniformly to this limit

Comment: Actually the limit is $|x|$. TO prove uniform convergence, try to use the definition.

Comment: Have you looked at the definition of uniform convergence?

Comment: @Crostful yes it is, I will edit that in

Comment: To converge uniformly you need a set where setup the sequence of functions!!!

Comment: @Masacroso how do I go about that?

Comment: This sequence is uniformly convergent on the whole of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @KennyWong how do I show that?

Comment: Let me ask a second time: what is the definition of uniform convergence?

Comment: $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<e$ for every $n>N$ and for every $x$ in $D$

Comment: Are you sure you got the "for all"s and the "there exist"'s sorted out there?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_n(x)=\sqrt{x^2+\frac 1n}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and all $n\in\mathbb{N}^\star$.

Clearly, the sequence $(f_n)$ converges pointwise on $\mathbb{R}$ to $f:x\mapsto\left|x\right|$.

Now :

$$0\le f_n(x)-f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+\frac1n}-\sqrt{x^2}=\frac{1}{n\left(\sqrt{x^2+\frac1n}+\left|x\right|\right)}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$$

which proves uniform convergence on $\mathbb{R}$.

**Remark**

This gives a very simple example of a sequence of smooth functions which converges uniformly to a non-differentiable one.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will take the time to try and understand your workings

Answer (score 0):

Remembering the reverse triangle inequality, for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$
\begin{align*}
|f(x)-f_n(x)|&=\left|\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}-|x|\right|\\
&\leq\left|\sqrt{x^2+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{n}}-|x|\right|\\
&=\left|\left|x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right|-|x|\right|\\
& \leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.
\end{align*}
We also used the fact $n>0$. Now from here I hope you can find, for any $\varepsilon >0$, a $N_\varepsilon$ such that $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}<\varepsilon$ whenever $n>N_\varepsilon$. The result then follows immediately.

Comment: how do I find that $N_e$

Comment: Think of what we want. We know $n>N_\varepsilon \implies 1/n<1/N_\varepsilon$, and that the square root is a monotone function. This should suggest a $N_\varepsilon$ in terms of $\varepsilon$.

Comment: would $\frac{1}{sqrt{N}}$ work?

Comment: @user19090 considering you want to end up showing that $n>N_\varepsilon\implies 1/\sqrt{n}<\varepsilon$ I think not. Think of what should be in place of your undefined $N$.